# Vim mapping to copy all text in visual mode

Tags: vim

I would like to map ctrl+a in visual mode to select and copy all text from the current buffer.

The basic idea is to execute: %y* (copy all buffer to clipboard). So, the mapping should be: xmap  :%y* (xmap for visual mode only)

However, whenever I run this mapping, this output is shown:

```
E492: Not an editor command: '<,'>%y*
```

And, I think Vim is right :-). When in **visual mode**, pressing the ":", makes the cmd-line show those surprising characters:

```
":'<,'>"
```

The only relevant piece of info where I could find this pattern ('<,'>) is that one: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#v_:
(and it didn't help me).

Question: Am I doing something wrong (configuration...) ? Is there another answer to my need (copy all text to clipboard) ?

*I am running Vim 7.3 and I only set nocompatible in my vimrc*

Thanks for your help,
Tom

Comment: `'<,'>` means the selected region.

Comment: also see `:help v_:` about those “strange” marks…

Comment: @Sebastian Paaske Tørholm: to be more accurate, it means the range of *lines* on which the selection extends.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
xnoremap <whatever> :<c-u>%y*<return>
```

The additional <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>u</kbd> erases the command line till the cursor.

From vim reference:

```
                            *c_CTRL-U*
CTRL-U  Remove all characters between the cursor position and
        the beginning of the line.  Previous versions of vim
        deleted all characters on the line.  If that is the
        preferred behavior, add the following to your .vimrc: >
        :cnoremap <C-U> <C-E><C-U>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following mapping:

```
nmap <C-A> ggVGy
```

It yanks all the current file. By the way, I'm not sure it's exactly what you what. I don't understand why you want a visual mapping.

Comment: Ctrl+a is bound to increment number in normal mode, by default. And, I think the Visual mode is what I should use to "select" text, no ?

Comment: @Tom: you use visual mode to *select* text, and you use the `y` command to copy (yank) it. Since your goal is to yank, forget visual mode.

Comment: Btw, you can do the same without going through visual mode: `ggyG`.

Comment: Yep right. If you want to yank text you have to forget about visual mode for sure.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The idea was to not override ctrl+a in normal mode, already mapped to increment number. So I thought of using the Visual mode.